# Javascript: adding styles to file line by line

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I have a plaintext file that is served online using a webserver. It is a log with the following format:

```
[00:24:48] <username> message text goes here
```

I want to make some javascript to format the logs line by line and apply different styles to the timestamp, username and message. How do I read the text in line by line and apply css styles?

Comment: Why aren't you using the web server to format it once into HTML and serve that? Formatting it every time on the client using script is not a very efficient use of resources.

Comment: I hope to add this functionality as a browser extension or userscript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yLtAz/)

```
var line = "[00:24:48] <username> message text goes here";
// stamp
line =  line.replace(/(\[[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\])/, '<span class="stamp">$1</span>');
// username
line =  line.replace(/<([a-zA-Z]+)>/, '<span class="user">&lt;$1&gt;</span>');

$('#id').html('<div class="message">' + line + '</div>');
```

I would use [**jQuery for the ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) just because it's so simple to implement:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/log.txt',
    success: function(lines) {
        processLines(lines.split('\n'));
    }
})

function processLines(arrayOfLines) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfLines.length; i++) {
        var line = arrayOfLines[i]; //"[00:24:48] <username> message text goes here";
        // stamp
        line = line.replace(/(\[[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\])/, '<span class="stamp">$1</span>');
        line = line.replace(/<([a-zA-Z]+)>/, '<span class="user">&lt;$1&gt;</span>');

        $('#id').html('<div class="message">' + line + '</div>');
    }
})
```

Comment: IAbstractDownvoteFactory, how do I read each line into the line variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to generate a single HTML string:

```
var t = ' [00:24:48] username message text goes here ';
var r = /(\[)([^\]]+)(\] +)(\S+)/g;
var html = t.replace(r, '<span class="timestamp">$2<\/span>' +
                        '<span class="username">$4<\/span> <span class="message">') +
                        '<\/span><br>';

//  <span class="timestamp">00:24:48</span><span class="username">username</span>'
//  <span class="message"> message text goes here </span><br>
```

though you might need to use the multiline flag (m), depending on the input.